# Angular 6 build --prod - /dist 7x size of /src. Sound about right?

Tags: angular

My first production build is 777kb.  My /src file is 117kb.  Of course I expect the build to be larger due to dependences but I couldn't find much info online that gives me guidance on if my build is reasonable or if I have issues to solve.  Most of the app is lazy loaded but I assume that doesn't matter for build size.

Your experience would be appreciated.  Is 7x within reason?

Note to down voters.  This isn't about opinion, it is about coding my app appropriately.  I'm looking for a specific metric, it is not too broad.

Comment: The range of appropriate sizes is entirely variable based on your dependency tree. There exists no such thing as a right answer with only the information given. "How much space is required for dependencies X, Y and Z?" would at least be a question that has an answer, but not one likely to help other people (since dependency trees necessarily vary project-to-project). We couldn't say what a ratio could/should be, because *as a percentage* the size needed for any given dependency tree will vary in relation to your code depending on how much code you have.

Comment: ...if you have 50MB of your own code and a tiny dependency tree, the ratio will be tiny. If you have 2 lines of code and a large dependency tree, the ratio will be huge. There exists no right answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy!  That makes sense and answers the question.  Please post as an answer and I'll mark it, before the down voters close this.

Comment: Feel free to transfer that content to an answer yourself; tag it "community wiki" if you don't want personal credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charles Duffy answered this but didn't want credit.  So for those of you looking for a metric as I did, it is impossible to use one such as the ratio of /src to /dist.  It would be nice if such a ratio was possible.

"The range of appropriate sizes is entirely variable based on your dependency tree. There exists no such thing as a right answer with only the information given. "How much space is required for dependencies X, Y and Z?" would at least be a question that has an answer, but not one likely to help other people (since dependency trees necessarily vary project-to-project).

We couldn't say what a ratio could/should be, because as a percentage the size needed for any given dependency tree will vary in relation to your code depending on how much code you have.

If you have 50MB of your own code and a tiny dependency tree, the ratio will be tiny. If you have 2 lines of code and a large dependency tree, the ratio will be huge. There exists no right answer to this question." – Charles Duffy

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the size of the project, also you can gzip etc.

I used this article to gaugemy bundle sizes and make adjustments based on the sizes.

Using Webpack bundle analyzer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer 
`npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-analyzer`

https://coryrylan.com/blog/analyzing-bundle-size-with-the-angular-cli-and-webpack

Comment: Thank you @Taranjit.  Looks like a useful tool and I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

/src only contains your code, and essentials. /node_modules contains all your dependencies, which gets compiled in with `ng build --prod`. So yeah, it makes sense.